# How to print through jquery the content of a php foreach?

Tags: php, jquery

I have the problem that I print the DIV but the content of the foreach is empty and I print NaN, I started to move the accents and quotation marks and now I throw error of a token <. I have been fighting with this for 2 hours and I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
function activateButtonSend(action){
    var addButton = "";
    var php = "";
    if (action === true) {
        php += @php
            App\Models\Activity::getOptionsForMail()->map(function($name,$id){
                echo "<a class='dropdown-item btn-act-".$id."' href='javascript:sendComments(".$id.");'>".$name."</a>";
            });
        @endphp
        addButton = "<div class='f-flex float-right' id='dropdown-activities'>\
                        <button id='content-message' style='display: none' type='button' class='btn btn-lg iq-bg-primary-abs dropdown-toggle'\
                            data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>\
                                Guardar\
                        </button>\
                        <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='btnGroupDrop1'>'"+php+"'</div>\
                    </div>";
    }else{
        addButton = '<button type="submit" id="content-message" style="display: none" class="btn iq-bg-primary-abs btn-lg float-right action-button-submit">Guardar</button>';
    }

    $('#type_buttons').html(addButton);
}
```

Message error console

[image]

[image]

It prints the results but throws an error because it does not take the tilde to join it inside the php variable of jquery.

@php is the abbreviation of `<?php ?>`

Comment: What is `@php` supposed to be? I've never seen that syntax before. PHP code goes between `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: @Barmar It is the abbreviation of <?php ?> this one with Laravel.

Comment: @Barmar I put the same thing you put and it still throws the error, Unexpected token '<'.  in the line php

Comment: why dont you just do a ajax call to the php script to grab the data and then do whatever you need in javascript without having to inject php stuff

Answer (score 1):

You're generating JavaScript code, but you're not putting quotes around the JS string. The best way to turn a PHP value into a JavaScript literal is to call `json_encode()` when echoing.

```
function activateButtonSend(action){
    var addButton = "";
    var php = "";
    if (action === true) {
        php += @php
            App\Models\Activity::getOptionsForMail()->map(function($name,$id){
                echo json_encode("<a class='dropdown-item btn-act-".$id."' href='javascript:sendComments(".$id.");'>".$name."</a>");
            });
        @endphp
        addButton = "<div class='f-flex float-right' id='dropdown-activities'>\
                        <button id='content-message' style='display: none' type='button' class='btn btn-lg iq-bg-primary-abs dropdown-toggle'\
                            data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>\
                                Guardar\
                        </button>\
                        <div class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='btnGroupDrop1'>'"+php+"'</div>\
                    </div>";
    }else{
        addButton = '<button type="submit" id="content-message" style="display: none" class="btn iq-bg-primary-abs btn-lg float-right action-button-submit">Guardar</button>';
    }

    $('#type_buttons').html(addButton);
}
```

Comment: Also helpful after you `json_decode()` to escape it. Say using `htmlentities()`